# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12847: retry parsing due to concurrent DDL operation

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm reading data from Oracle DB on python cx_Oracle. But sometimes it throws

> ORA-12847: retry parsing due to concurrent DDL operation

I couldn't find anything about it on internet. It's just a select statement with some joins. Query result has almost 10M rows. There is nothing wrong in explain plan.

here is my code snippet:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    #cursor.prefetchrows = 2000000
    cursor.arraysize = 250000
    cursor.execute(query)
    data_list = cursor.fetchall()
    data_columns = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
    print("I got %d lines " % len(data_list))
```

the error occurs at **cursor.fetchall()** line.

Comment: From what I gather, this is some internal error perhaps related to PL/SQL or parallel SQL.  The best thing to do is ask Oracle Support to help you investigate.  Perhaps related is your oversized arraysize. Is such a large size really helpful?  It will certainly chew lots of memory in the various stacks. Try reducing it.  And don't set prefetchrows.  And ugprade to [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: This can happen when a cursor is invalidated during parallel execution. This could be (but not limited to ) DDL on a schema object, or shared pool being flushed...

Comment: @ChristopherJones i asked Oracle Support but no response yet. i don't use prefetchrows, just tried and comment out it. dataset i try to read has ~10million rows. small arraysize takes long and it causes timeout. thus, i had to give bigger arraysize. i couldn't upgrade to python-oracledb, it is prod env.

Comment: @BobC i just have a select statement, there is no DDL operation. connection i make doesn't come from a share pool.

Comment: What smaller values did you use?  What was the timeout?

Comment: I tried 5000, 10k, 100k. If run time pass 60 minutes, db throws timeout error.